# How to merge contours in OpenCV or adjust?

Tags: android, kotlin, opencv, svg

I'm using OpenCV in Kotlin to detect black lines, but it always gives me the cotours of the black lines and because this they are not connecting at all, it would be necessary, bc i will have to convert it into graphs and then use a pathfinding on it!

So how can i do it to merge/make only one contour between those ?

Other solution would be if it could detect crossroads/junction and then be able to make connections like an X in a cube like this:

[image]

Here is the code:
private fun convertSnapshotImageOpenCV(context: Context) {
OpenCVLoader.initDebug()

```
    val imagePath = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "gps_app/map_snapshot.png")

    // Betöltés Mat objektumba
    val image = Imgcodecs.imread(imagePath.absolutePath, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) // Átalakítjuk szürkeárnyalatos képpé

    // Az alsó rész levágása
    val cropHeight = image.rows() / 9 // Alsó 9%-át levágni a Google logó miatt
    val croppedImage = image.submat(0, image.rows() - cropHeight, 0, image.cols())

    // Csak a fekete vonalak tartása meg
    val result = Mat()
    Core.inRange(croppedImage, Scalar(0.0), Scalar(25.0), result) // A 0.0 és 100.0 határok az értékfüggőek lehetnek, módosítsd szükség szerint

    val contours = ArrayList<MatOfPoint>()
    Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(croppedImage, result, 255.0, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 25, 12.0)
    Imgproc.findContours(result, contours, Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        croppedImage.cols(),
        croppedImage.rows(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )

    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE) // Beállítjuk a háttérszínt fehérre

    for (contour in contours) {
        val points = ArrayList<Point>(contour.toList())
        val path = Path()
        val svgPathData = StringBuilder("M") // "M" az "move to" SVG parancs

        if (points.isNotEmpty()) {
            svgPathData.append("${points[0].x},${points[0].y}")  // Kezdőpont hozzáadása
        }

        for (i in 1 until points.size) {
            path.lineTo(points[i].x.toFloat(), points[i].y.toFloat())
            svgPathData.append(" L ${points[i].x},${points[i].y}") // "L" az "line to" SVG parancs
        }

        path.close()
        svgPathData.append(" Z") // "Z" az "close path" SVG parancs
        DataHolder.pathData.add(svgPathData.toString()) // SVG path adat hozzáadása az osztályszintű változóhoz
        Log.d("MyApp: - pathData main: ", DataHolder.pathData.toString())

        val paint = Paint()
        paint.color = Color.BLACK
        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
    }

    val svgString = createSVGFromPathData(DataHolder.pathData)

    val directory = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "gps_app")
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs()
    }

    val svgFile = File(directory, "convertedSVG_Map.svg")
    svgFile.writeText(svgString)
}
```

I tried some other ways but these not worked well :(